# pgf sci E notation: How to print 0 instead of 0e+0 automatically

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there a way to use the sci E notation of pgfs math number printing but getting 0 instead of 0E+0? I know I could just change the style by hand before printing the zero. But I am looking for an *automated* way which works in pgfplots without manual replacement of labels.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci E}
Aim:\\
0 \hspace{1em} 1.23E+1\par
Actual:\\
\pgfmathprintnumber{0}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.345}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you only going to use `\pgfmathprintnumber` or planning to do computations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to hack into `\pgfmathprintnumber`, in particular the `sci E` notation.  But for compatibility it is better to keep the original `sci E` and introduce a new `sci E skip E+0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter

\def\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@Eskipzero#1#2e#3\relax{%
  \ifnum#3<0\relax
    \pgfmathprintnumber@begingroup
    \count0=#3\relax
    \multiply\count0 by-1
    \xdef\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP{E{-}\the\count0}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber@endgroup%
    \let\pgfmathresult=\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP
  \else
    \ifnum#3=0\relax
      \def\pgfmathresult{}%
    \else
      \def\pgfmathresult{E{+}#3}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \def\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb{\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl#1#2e#3\relax{}{1}}%
  \expandafter\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/number format/sci E skip E+0/.code={%
    \let\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle=\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@Eskipzero
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci E skip E+0}
Aim:\\
0 \hspace{1em} 1.23E+1\par
Actual:\\
\pgfmathprintnumber{0}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.345}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Instead of a new number format, you could make it a conditional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter

\def\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@Eskipzero#1#2e#3\relax{%
  \ifnum#3<0\relax
    \pgfmathprintnumber@begingroup
    \count0=#3\relax
    \multiply\count0 by-1
    \xdef\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP{E{-}\the\count0}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber@endgroup%
    \let\pgfmathresult=\pgfmathfloat@glob@TMP
  \else
    \ifnum#3=0\relax
      \def\pgfmathresult{}%
    \else
      \def\pgfmathresult{E{+}#3}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \def\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb{\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl#1#2e#3\relax{}{1}}%
  \expandafter\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\newif\ifpgfmathprintnumberskipEzero

\let\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@Ewithzero=\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@E

\def\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@E{%
  \ifpgfmathprintnumberskipEzero
    \expandafter\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@Eskipzero
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@Ewithzero
  \fi
}

\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/number format/skip E+0/.is if=pgfmathprintnumberskipEzero,
  /pgf/number format/skip E+0/.default=true,
  /pgf/number format/skip E+0=false,
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci E,skip E+0}
Aim:\\
0 \hspace{1em} 1.23E+1\par
Actual:\\
\pgfmathprintnumber{0}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.345}
\end{document}
```

The output is similar.